# Help me perfect out my current linear algebra knowledge

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> My questions  are along my workings, I have attempted both the parts  as much as possible as I can. Please help me on this question. My question comes as (i) Is my proof perfect? (ii) Am I correct?

---

[image]

---

What  I did:

**Part (i)**

$$a \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} + c \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 51 \\ 55 \end{pmatrix} = 0$$

$$a+2b+5c=0$$

$$5a-3b+51c=0$$

$$7a+4b+55c=0$$

**REDUCED ROW ECHLEON FORM:**

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 5 & -3 & 51 \\ 7 & 4 & 55 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 0 & -13 & 26 \\ 0 & -10 & 20 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 9 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$a=-9c$$

$$b=2c$$

$$c=c$$

So $a,b$ are linearly dependant on $c$ . Where $c$ is the free variable.

Is this proof too long?

**Is my proof perfect?**

---

**Part (iii)**

I don't know well how to approach this, Il try :

From **(i)**

I Can find the  basis of $y_1,y_2,y_3$, as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} = c \begin {pmatrix} 2 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So the basis is :

span of $$\begin {pmatrix} 2 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

**So for the basis of $Py_1, Py_2, Py_3$ I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) , I can write as :**

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -4 & 3 \\ 0 & 2 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & -7 \end{pmatrix} \begin {pmatrix} 2 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 41 \\ -13 \\ -7 \end{pmatrix}$$

> Reason I believe : is because of a previous part of the question, where  I Showed the following:  "Three $n × 1$ column vectors are denoted by $x_1, x_2, x_3$, and M is an $n × n$ matrix. Show that if $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are linearly dependent then the vectors $Mx_1, Mx_2, Mx_3$ are also linearly dependent"

Therefore **basis** :

Span of $$\begin{pmatrix} 41 \\ -13 \\ -7 \end{pmatrix}$$

**Am I correct?**

Comment: These should be at least three separate questions. Maybe even ask just one question, learn from the responses, then post the next question.

Comment: @DavidK , shall I separate the first part and the second two parts ? Such that it makes 2 question? The reason is that (i) and (ii) are very related, and I have used (i) to (ii) ? Do you think that's better? :)

Comment: OK, make it two questions. The second part is much longer than the first, so it _looked_ like it might be two questions, but it really isn't.

Comment: @DavidK , the first part has actually almost nothing to answer, it's a "yes or a no" answer. It's the other two parts. So removing the first part wouldnt change the question much, it's just my working that makes the question seem long.

Comment: @DavidK , but yes :) you must be knowing better :) Il cut the first part off this question :)

Comment: @DavidK , completed the task :) I edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i)$ Your method is correct.  Your conclusion is a little bit wrong: you're conflating your set $\{a, b, c\}$ with $\{y_1, y_2, y_3\}$.  The conclusion should actually be something like "Thus $\{y_1,\ y_2\}$ is a linearly independent set while $\{y_1,\ y_2,\ y_3\}$ is not".  (NOTE: your basis is $2$-dimensional, not $1$-D)

$ii)$ You CANNOT find a basis for $y_1, y_2,$ and $y_3$ by setting $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} = c\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -9 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$  (again, you're conflating $\{a, b, c\}$ with $\{y_1, y_2, y_3\}$).  The space $\text{span}(y_1,\ y_2,\ y_3)$ will necessarily be $2$-dimensional because $\{y_1,\ y_2\}$ **is a linearly independent set**.  In fact, one basis of $\text{span}(y_1,\ y_2,\ y_3)$ is definitely $\{y_1,\ y_2\}$ (as you showed in part $(i)$).

Then you use the theorem that tells you that linearly independent vectors map to linearly independent vectors under a full rank transformation (and dependent vectors to dependent vectors), so because $\{y_1,\ y_2\}$ is a basis of $\text{span}(y_1,\ y_2,\ y_3)$, $\{Py_1,\ Py_2\}$ is a basis of $\text{span}(Py_1,\ Py_2,\ Py_3)$.

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much :D but , I did not show that $y_1,y_2$ are linearly independant right?

Comment: It says to show that they are "linearly dependent".  "Linearly dependent" means "NOT linearly independent".

Comment: :) re read my comment now :)

Comment: By finding the reduced row echelon form of the form, you found that the rank is 2.  Thus 2 of your 3 vectors will be linearly independent of each other.  If you can't immediately see that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are 2 such linearly independent vectors, then just prove it.

Comment: Got it :) Thank you a lot :)